# JavaScript image objects

Tags: javascript, html, image, object

I would either like a way to relatively position objects to the upper left corner of a div. or a way to use JavaScript to create some sort of image view (without using HTML img tag) that will display on screen relative to a div. there will be multiple of these images and I want them to be able to overlappable. I'm trying to remake a game I've made on Xcode which involves blocks that move around aligned to a grid (which will be in a window that is 1000x700px)

I'm a beginner with javascript

Comment: -1. Sorry, but your question is just not detailed and researched enough. It's kinda confusing, and you provide no context as to why you want to avoid using the HTML `<img>` tag. By the way, there are three ways to add an image in HTML. 1) directly specify an `<img>` tag, 2) in a script tag, create an instance of `Image()` and use `element.appendChild()`. If you're willing to use canvas, then 3) create a `<canvas>` element and use `context.drawImage()`.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the first option (positioning images), you can accomplish that with just CSS (or manipulate the same CSS properties with JavaScript). You just need:

1. A container with `position: relative`.
2. Elements inside with `position: absolute`. Then manipulate their `top`, `left`, `right` and `bottom` properties (which will be relative to the container).

Answer (score 0):

Well its hard to recommend anything without full context, but you can do this with some basic CSS.

Since you don't want to use image tags you can add a background image on the containing div. Then position that image where ever you need it.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ufomammut66/wctJc/1/

We're using a `background-position` to define where to show the image. You can use relational (top, center, bottom, right, left) or actual pixel locations (X Y notation IE: 100px 5px) to tell define where it should display.

Depending on what kind of stuff you're going to be doing (since it's a game) it may make more sense to break items out into different children of the main container. So you would have 1 element that has its `position:relative` on it and a series of other elements that have `position:absolute` on them. The absolutely positioned elements can be placed just like the background - with X Y locations set in pixels (`top:100px;left:5px`). Additionally you can animate them to move around and interact with things. In the below example I used jQuery to animate the element, mostly because jQuery makes animation super easy.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ufomammut66/QxGhD/2/